# How can I install mmc-utils on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, devices

According to [this article](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/mmc-utils) `mmc-utils` may be installed on Ubuntu 17.04 with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mmc-utils
```

But that doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 for me. Is there a straightforward way to install it?

Comment: 14.04 and 17.04, what's the connection?

Comment: E.g. it is not unusual that packages for different versions of ubuntu have different names.

Comment: According to the [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mmc-utils) it is not available in trusty (exists only in zesty, artful, bionic).

Comment: @N0rbert You are right. Can I built in myself?

Comment: I hope you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following on 16.04 LTS.

For installation of `mmc-utils` do the following:

1. Install development packages `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. Download `mmc-utils` sources and extract them

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mmc-utils/mmc-utils_0~gita3d3331.orig.tar.xz

   tar -xf mmc-utils_0~gita3d3331.orig.tar.xz
   cd mmc-utils-0~gita3d3331
   ```
3. Install checkinstall to make deb-package with `sudo apt-get install checkinstall`

Start deb-package creation with `sudo checkinstall make install` and then in checkinstall session do the following:

1. for *Should I create a default set of package docs?* answer <kbd>n</kbd> .
2. enter *mmc-utils* as package description and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>;
3. enter 2 and enter *mmc-utils* as package Name, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
4. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue (start compilation and deb-package building)

You can verify installation of your package with `apt-cache policy mmc-utils`

```
mmc-utils:
  Installed: 0~gita3d3331-1
  Candidate: 0~gita3d3331-1
  Version table:
 *** 0~gita3d3331-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The binary is located in `/usr/local/bin/mmc` and can be launched as `mmc`.

Comment: If I press Enter in step 4. the installation aborts?

Comment: I updated my post, fixed some typos. It should compile successfully.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks for the answer. How can I execute the interactive `sudo checkinstall make install` procedure as part of a script?

Comment: I do not know. Usually I do this once and manually.