# Getting "make install" error with Wine 3.0 Stable

Tags: wine

I have configured Wine 3.0. I have run the `make` command. After 30 minutes, Wine is built, but `make install` fails:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hafeez/Downloads/wine-3.0/winecrt0'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hafeez/Downloads/wine-3.0/acledit'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hafeez/Downloads/wine-3.0/dlls/acledit'
STRIPPROG="strip" ./tools/install-sh dlls/acledit/acledit.dll.so /usr/local/lib/wine/acledit.dll.so
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/lib/wine‘: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/lib/wine‘: Permission denied
Makefile:1608: recipe for target 'dlls/acledit/install-lib' failed
make: *** [dlls/acledit/install-lib] Error 1
```

How do I get `make install` to install Wine?

Comment: figure link is given

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for terminal text. Instead, paste the text into your question, select the text, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: got it.........

Answer (score 2):

The command `make install` will not complete successfully unless it is prefaced by `sudo` like this:

```
sudo make install
```

To run a Windows program in wine, you need to type `wine c:\\path\\to\\app`. It will normally be in the Program Files folder of `\home\user\.wine`.

If you installed Wine from source, use `sudo rm` to delete the wine files from the directory where you installed them (usually `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: ohh ..oops i was following exact text given readme..

Comment: Dear karel, why do not suggest to install with `checkinstall`?  `make install` create difficulties in supporting system later.

Comment: That's what it says to do in the readme.

Comment: And what? Many software is installed by unpack, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`. All such installations may trash the system. Even if they installed in `/opt` or `/usr/local`, because all they will be in PATH. So I recommend to [read about `checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package).

Answer (score 1):

What you did is not recommended.

Better way is install self-compiled applications with
[`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package) (`sudo apt-get install checkinstall`)
to make deb-packages with it.
You can use my [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984176/66509) for complete instruction.

Or install Wine from [WineHQ official repository for Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winehq-stable # for trusty, xenial and artful
```

Commands above will install Wine 3.0.

Comment: I have done that before but it installed wine 2.X

Comment: It depends on your Ubuntu version. 16.04 LTS has winehq-stable 3.0.0~xenial, 17.10 has winehq-stable 3.0.0~artful.